# Rewrite shorter version function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-functional-component

I have a function that calls out particular states but with a semi-identical lines.  Here's my function;

```js
DoThis(type) {
   if (type === 'a') {
      this.setState({ activeA: { display: 'block', opacity: 1 } }, () => setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({ activeA: { opacity: 0 } }, () => setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ activeA: { display: 'none' } })
         }, 300))
      }, 2000));
   } else if (type === 'b') {
      this.setState({ activeB: { display: 'block', opacity: 1 } }, () => setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({ activeB: { opacity: 0 } }, () => setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ activeB: { display: 'none' } })
         }, 300))
      }, 2000));
   } // ...some other active(n) conditions.
}
```

It's pretty messy and I just want it to be free from congestion.

This is my state:

```js
this.state ={
   activeA: { display: 'none', opacity: 0 },
   activeB: { display: 'none', opacity: 0 },
   // ...some other active(n) states...
}
```

Any way of resolving this kind of issue?

Comment: `this.setState({ \`active${type.toUpperCase()}\`: ... })`?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with all these setStates? It doesnt make sense at all to me. Why isn't this all in one setState and what are those setTimeouts doing?

Comment: first use switch case for multiple if else statements. Then make 2 functions one makes a state active and another one inactive or make one function just toggles the state. And you can use string literals as keys for javascript objects like this : ` {'active'+stateToActivate :{ display:"block", opacity:1 }}` that is what @jonrsharpe trying to tell you. So all you need to take a parameter as the name of that state.

Comment: @DaveMoreno, you can derive the value of `display` from `opacity` in the render function `const display = state.opacity > 0 ? "" : "none";` *(don't use `block` here, let it fall back to whatever is defined in CSS)* this already eliminates the second `setTimeout` including the third `setState`.

Comment: @Mirakurun. It's a version of self-close modal. Basically, when I click that particular button, a certain modal prior to the states will pop-up, and will close on its own.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. This looks like a great idea. The thing is, I'm a reactjs newbie... Can you "state" the specifics?

Comment: Have you considered using [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html) ?

Comment: That's nothing to do with React, really; run through a basic JS/ES6 tutorial to get a grasp of the syntax available, it's just a template string

Answer (score 1):

To escape the callback hell, you can add a simple function like this:

```
const delay = (time = 0) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time));
```

And then rewrite that in the linear fashion:

```
async DoThis(type) {
    let key = 'active' + type.toUpperCase();

    this.setState({[key]: {display: 'block', opacity: 1}})
    await delay(300);
    this.setState({[key]: {opacity: 0}});
    await delay(2000);
    this.setState({[key]: {display: 'none'}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
DoThis(type) {
  const fieldName = `active${type.toUpperCase()}`;
  this.setState({[fieldName]: { display: 'block', opacity: 1 } }, () => setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({ [fieldName]: { opacity: 0 } }, () => setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ fieldName]: { display: 'none' } })
     }, 300))
  }, 2000));
}
```

Template strings let you easily construct a string with complex JavaScript values:

```
  const myString = "some text";
  const myTemplateString = `you can insert ${myString} into a template string`;
  // myTemplateString = "you can insert some text into a template string"
```

Computed property values let you assign values to the fields of an object without knowing ahead of time (i.e. "hard coding") what the fields are:

```
  const myFieldName = "pizza";
  const myObject = {
    [myFieldName]: "delicious"
  };
  // myObject = {pizza: "delicious"}
```

Comment: Would definitely try this.